# Is it possible to create a timeuuid that is guaranteed to be idempotent based on a particular point in time?

Tags: python, cassandra, cql3

I am dealing with creating unique ids for a series of objects based in a distributed application and i want to make use of uuids. I understand that version 1 uuids are time based and I'd like to know if its possible to create a uuid that's guaranteed to be idempotent given a fixed point in time?

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1); you would need to supply `clock_seq` and be running with the same host ID.

Answer (score 0):

An idempotent timeuuid?  The `mintimeuuid()` function might help you out here.  Take this simple table definition, which uses a `timeuuid` as a clustering key:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow2.timeuuids (
    bucket text,
    value timeuuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (bucket, value));
```

Insert a row with a timestamp value into the (text) time `bucket`, and use the same timestamp value with the `mintimeuuid()` function.  Run that same INSERT several times:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> INSERT INTO timeuuids (bucket, value) VALUES ('2015-05-18 09:31',mintimeuuid('2015-05-18 09:31'));
```

And query for your time bucket:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM timeuuids WHERE bucket='2015-05-18 09:31';

 bucket           | value
------------------+--------------------------------------
 2015-05-18 09:31 | 80f72a00-fd6a-11e4-8080-808080808080

(1 rows)
```

Note that only one row is returned.  For more information, check out [this section of the CQL documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html).